# Importing mysql dump without overwriting existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I accidentally replaced all records for a field in a mysql table with NULL and am attempting to restore a backup so I can run an update query between my current table and the backup.  I created a new db called db_bckup, left it empty, then tried to import it from the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p db_bckup < mysqlbackupfile.sql
```

I assumed this would load the backup to my db_bckup database which was empty.  To my surprise, it overwrote my original database rather than loading into db_bckup.  In looking at the contents of the sql file, I noted that the contents include lines:

```
Host: localhost     Database: db
-------------------------------------------
Server version      5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1

[SET a bunch of things]

Current Database: 'db'

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ 'db' /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE 'db';

[table specific stuff]
```

I suspect that the references to 'db' in the sql file is overriding my command line import code.

My question is: Is it the sql file or command line that's causing the overwrite?  If the sql file is the cause, is it a matter of editing the backup file manually to change the db name to db_bckup or is there a more administrative way to change all the 'db' references within the file to 'db_bckup'?  I am a little wary of messing with the backup file, so I'd like to take the best approach those with more experience would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify db_name when mysqldump, `USE db_name` will not printed in it's output. I guess that you tried `--databases` or `--all-database`

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]  <= you need to run mysqldump this way
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

and FYI, mysqldump provides option which not create table.

```
  -t, --no-create-info Don't write table creation info.
```

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future backups.  My backup file already has the USE db info in it, so I'm looking for a way to import this file without overwriting my existing db.

Comment: @user2280711 Unfortunately you need to edit sql file. I guess your sql file is too big to edit. do you know about sed? sed may help you to edit easier. Or i am wrong, please explain what is your problem.